# glTexImage2D with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT works on iOS4 , and fails with GL_INVALID_ENUM in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios5, opengl-es, ios4, glteximage2d

Following code works without errors  on iOS 4 and prints in CHECK_GL_ERROR macro  0x500 after glTexImage2D on iOS5.
I searched for info on this, but did not find anything useful.

```
GLuint depthTexId = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &depthTexId);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexId);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 512, 512, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
CHECK_GL_ERROR();
```

I've tried to change parameters of glTexImage2D, but have no success.
Why is it working so? What is the difference between iOS 4 and 5?
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have replaced GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE with GL_UNSIGNED_INT, and the code began to work both on iOS 4 and iOS 5.